# Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'TooManyPagesException' #0 MultiPage.generate

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, pdf-generation, dart-pdf

Updated:
This error is on IOS only.
I dont know why but its working fine on android.
I was facing an issue in Flutter using the pdf package and the issue was:
Widget won't fit into the page as its height (823.408) exceed a page height (728.5039370078739). You probably need a SpanningWidget or use a single page layout.

Then I try to warp my pdf content to a SpanningWidget i.e. Wrap widget. But after I get another which seems to be a new error.

`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'TooManyPagesException' #0      MultiPage.generate (package:pdf/src/widgets/multi_page.dart:251:9) #1      Document.addPage (package:pdf/src/widgets/document.dart:117:10) #2      _QuillPageState.generatePdf (package:daiaryapp/pages/addDairyPage/quill_page.dart:76:9) <asynchronous suspension> #3      _QuillPageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:daiaryapp/pages/addDairyPage/quill_page.dart:320:48) <asynchronous suspension>`

This is my Code :

```
pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        final content = <pw.Widget>[];

        content.add(
          pw.Center(
            child: pw.Text(
              post.dairyName.toString(), // Replace with your desired title
              style: customTitle,
            ),
          ),
        );

        int itemsPerPage = 8;

        for (var i = 0; i < deltaData['ops'].length; i++) {
          final op = deltaData['ops'][i];

          if (op.containsKey('insert')) {
            if (op['insert'] is String) {
              final lines = (op['insert'] as String).split('-');

              for (var line in lines) {
                final textWidget = pw.Padding(
                  padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: pw.Text(
                    line.trim(), // Trim to remove extra spaces
                    style: customTextStyle, // Apply custom text style here
                  ),
                );

                content.add(textWidget);
              }
            } else if (op['insert'] is Map &&
                op['insert'].containsKey('image')) {
              final imageData = op['insert']['image'].split(',')[1];
              final Uint8List decodedImage = base64Decode(imageData);

              final imageWidget = pw.Padding(
                padding: pw.EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                child: pw.Image(
                  pw.MemoryImage(
                    decodedImage,
                  ),
                  fit: pw.BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 245.0,
                ),
              );

              content.add(imageWidget);
            }
          }

          if (i > 0 && (i + 1) % itemsPerPage == 0) {
            content.add(pw.Container(width: 1.0, height: 1.0));
          }
        }

        // return content;
        return [
          pw.Wrap(
            children: content,
          ),
        ];
      },
    ));
```

I have tried multiple things, including Stackoverflow questions, GPT, and GitHub issue but didn't get anything helpful

Comment: im curious to you image widget, can you try to set the `width` property?  since you only set the height,

Comment: i have not added the image yet. this error comes only when i am trying to add text only

Comment: Any updates? Did you find out how to solve this?

Comment: no it still the same

Answer (score 0):

Basically column or wrap widget must be parent widget otherwise it takes a full page to expand it self. And when the content is lengthy then a page inside a column or wrap it gives this error. Don't use Wrap as your child widget.